Dealing with aggregate and hardcore in soil
I recently removed a thick layer of concrete and have been trying to remove the hardcore beneath.However, there is also a thick layer of red limestone aggregate in a deep layer that I cant remove mixed in with the hardcore. What impact will this have on the plants and can I mitigate it with compost and green waste (organic matter)?

Hi Kathe, welcome to the site!  If you leave the hardcore and aggregate in place, how much soil would you be putting on top of it?  And what are you planning to plant there (lawn, vegetables, trees...)?

Assuming you are putting some topsoil (or something like a mixture of sand and compost) on top of it, a "deep layer you can't remove" is just subsoil, as far as plants are concerned. Limestone of whatever color should be fine - it's not nuclear waste. Just want the rocks far enough below the surface to not impact any root vegetables you want to grow, and to have some soil with nutrients for the plants on top as well.
Only putting compost on top will take a lot of compost and not suit some plants (others will love it.)

HI again - many thanks for your answer. However, I'm not growing vegetables - more like small trees (eg magnolia) or forsythia, philadelphus, pom pom bush and climbing roses or honeysuckle. I know plants are sensitive to the PH so wouldnt all that limestone make it too alkali? Hance the need to rebalance with compost etc

Limestone in aggregate sizes does not generally have a huge effect on soil pH - it does not break down that quickly, which is why limestone intended to make a short-term difference in pH is finely ground.  The majority of feeding roots for trees and shrubs are in the surface layer of topsoil, which you can alter with compost and/or sulfur if it is too alkaline as tested. The preferred pH of your various small trees varies considerably - forsythia prefer somewhat alkaline soil, while roses prefer slightly acidic and magnolias prefer very acidic soils.
